# Event within Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have been having some issues figuring this out.

*Page 1*

```
<iframe id="block" src="page2.html" tag> </iframe>
```

I want to hover in the Iframe and trigger an event if the element that I am hovering has a certain tag.

```
$("*").hover(function(){
    var attr = $(this).attr('name');
    if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
        return; //do something
    }
});
```

I have tried multiple things but they all seem to want something just a bit different, I understand the firing of a event from a parent class. I don't seem to get how to do this though. The result that I want:

- I hover in the Iframe over an element that has `tag`
- I get a response on the end of the Iframe that I can work with further

I feel like I got very close but I just need a little piece of connecting code, hopefully someone can explain what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're on the same domain (you are) there is an easy way:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="block" src="page.html" onload="test()"></iframe>
<script>
function test() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('block');
    var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var element = doc.getElementById('hover');
    $(element).hover(function() {
        element.append("It's working!\n");
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: I now get that I need to get the document that is loaded in the `Iframe`. The thing I am having trouble understanding is how to do the `$("*").hover(function(){})` function that ONLY responds within the `Iframe`.

Comment: @Nytrix there you go

Comment: Thank you! This will lead me to my solution, it's not directly what I asked, but it will work.

Comment: @Nytrix Happy to help :)